# NextJs reloading when using next-i18next on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm having issues using next-i18next on my app. I did implement everything as needed, but my layout is always rerendering on pages where getStaticProps are implemented, and I should prevent that.

So I created a file called withStaticTranslations.ts, which I'm using on pages, but when I try to load it in _app.tsx or Layout it's not working. Here is the file:

```
import { GetStaticProps, GetStaticPropsContext, GetStaticPropsResult } from 'next';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';

type WithStaticTranslationsOptions = {
    namespaces?: string[];
};

export const withStaticTranslations = (
    getStaticPropsFunc?: GetStaticProps,
    { namespaces = ['common'] }: WithStaticTranslationsOptions = {}
): GetStaticProps => {
    return async (context: GetStaticPropsContext): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<any>> => {
        const translations = await serverSideTranslations(context.locale || 'en', namespaces);

        if (getStaticPropsFunc) {
            const pageStaticProps = await getStaticPropsFunc(context);

            if ('props' in pageStaticProps) {
                return {
                    props: {
                        ...translations,
                        ...pageStaticProps.props,
                    },
                };
            }

            return pageStaticProps;
        }

        return { props: translations };
    };
};
```

And example how I'm using it on the page:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import React from "react";
import ImageSlider from "@/components/Organisms/ImageSlider";
import { withStaticTranslations } from '@/composables/withStaticTranslations';
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';

const Home: NextPage = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <ImageSlider />
        </>
    )
}


export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = withStaticTranslations();

export default Home;
```

So, what would be the best way to prevent that reloading of the layout? Even if I implemented all translations in _app.tsx, I think it would cause performance issues, but still I have to prevent it even performance issues are caused. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to preventing the layout from reloading would be to use the `useTranslation` hook provided by `next-i18next` instead of using the `serverSideTranslations` function in your `withStaticTranslations` HOC.

Here is an example of how you could modify your withStaticTranslations function to use the useTranslation hook:

```
import { GetStaticProps, GetStaticPropsContext, GetStaticPropsResult } from 'next';
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

type WithStaticTranslationsOptions = {
  namespaces?: string[];
};

export const withStaticTranslations = (
  getStaticPropsFunc?: GetStaticProps,
  { namespaces = ['common'] }: WithStaticTranslationsOptions = {}
): GetStaticProps => {
  return async (context: GetStaticPropsContext): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<any>> => {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation(namespaces);
    const translations = await i18n.getInitialProps(context.locale || 'en', namespaces);

    if (getStaticPropsFunc) {
      const pageStaticProps = await getStaticPropsFunc(context);

      if ('props' in pageStaticProps) {
        return {
          props: {
            ...translations,
            ...pageStaticProps.props,
          },
        };
      }

      return pageStaticProps;
    }

    return { props: translations };
  };
};
```

Then, you can use the `withStaticTranslations` HOC on your page like this:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import React from "react";
import ImageSlider from "@/components/Organisms/ImageSlider";
import { withStaticTranslations } from '@/composables/withStaticTranslations';
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';

const Home: NextPage = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <ImageSlider />
    </>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = withStaticTranslations();

export default Home;
```

By using the useTranslation hook, the translations will be cached on the client-side and the layout won't need to be reloaded every time the page is visited.